# Creating a dynamic WebGrid after user selections (MVC4)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have several web grids in a single view all working perfectly, except I now need to make one grid dynamic. It will populate once the user makes certain selections in ddl filters. The grid will not have a data source on pageload, I will need to send a json request to the controller but how do i create a placeholder for the grid? I can't use
    @grid.GetHTML(...)

because it throws an error wanting a datasource. I was declaring the grid with a model initially:

```
var gridHistory = new WebGrid(
    Commissions.Models.CommissionHistoryModel.getCommissionHistory());
```

But now that I don't know the data I need until after the user makes selections, I was going to try to do something like this (which throws an error since I'm not supplying a datasource):

```
var gridHistory = new WebGrid();
```

How can I supply a datasource when I don't have it at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

you can create partial action (with httpget attribute) returning PartialView which contains your dynamic WebGrid. Each time user make changes to ddl you should render you partial via $.ajax to some placeholder in main view.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the WebGrid has a shortcoming of not doing database level paging.  If you have large amounts of data you will have some performance problems.

You might be interested in Dynamic MVC (http://dynamicmvc.com).  It will perform dynamic database level sorting, filtering, and paging.  It also exposes the the html in partial views so you can customize the html directly in more of an mvc style instead of a webforms control style.